# Why is the populate method inconsistent?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm populating across multiple levels like so:

```
User.findById(user._id).
populate({
        path: 'units',
        populate: {
            path: 'sensors issues',
            populate: {
                path: 'timeseries opened_by referenced_by',
                populate: {
                    path: 'created_by'
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .exec(function(err, user) {

    })
```

The problem is that sometimes, randomly, the timeseries field won't populate anything, but on refreshing it, it will work fine.  It's completely inconsistent.  Is there anything wrong with the query itself?